sympy.geometry - how do I get answer in terms of point operations - dot, add etc?
Here is a simple solution intended to find the crossing point of two parametric lines:
def symP2(name):
    # utility that defines components for a sympy point and the point
    g = inspect.stack()[1][0].f_globals #globals of caller

    x_name = name+'_x'
    x = symbols(x_name, real=True)
    g[x_name] = x

    y_name = name+'_y'
    y = symbols(y_name, real=True)
    g[y_name] = y

    return Point2D(x, y)

a = symP2('a')
b = symP2('b')
c = symP2('c')
d = symP2('d')

ab = b-a
cd = d-c

s,t = symbols("s t", real=True)
    
p = a+ab*s
q = c+cd*t
    
st = solve(p-q, (s,t,))

display(st)

The solution is given in components of the points: a_x, a_y etc, like so:

It would be much clearer to have a solution expressed in vector operations, including addition, subtraction and inner product.
Also, it would be nice to keeping the the solution in term of already defined sub-expressions 'ab' and 'cd'
How can this be done with sympy?
Thanks!

What do p and q look like?

Hi, I have added q and p to the printout above
